# Safe initialization vector when using openssl_encrypt

Tags: initialization-vector, openssl

Is php's `bin2hex(random_bytes(8))` safe for an initialization vector when using `openssl_encrypt()`?

```
$cipherText = openssl_encrypt(
    'Secret message.',
    'AES-256-CBC',
    'some key',
    OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,
    bin2hex(random_bytes(8))
);
```

Comment: **Just** `random_bytes(16)` would be secure, why do you think you need `bin2hex` precisely? The chance of collisions when using just 8 bytes / 64 bits is pretty high (due to the birthday problem).